# React Const Infinite Cycle

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, post, antd

I faced a problem when I was coding in React. I have the following segment of code:

```js
<Popconfirm
  placement="topRight"
  title="Are you sure to delete this task?"
  onConfirm={confirm} okText="Yes" cancelText="No"  // [1]
>
  <a>delete</a>
</Popconfirm>
```

and I have the confirm function like this:

```js
const confirm = () => {                             // [2]
  message
    .loading("Deleting...", 1.8)
    .then(() => message.success("Todo item deleted!", 1.3));
  postDeleteData('/todo/', { method: 'delete', keyid: 42})   // [3] 
    .then(data => {
      if (data.success) {window.location = '/todo/';}
    })
  console.log('confirmed');
};
```

Now, everything works fine so far. However, things won't work after I made the following changes:

1. Changed `confirm` to `confirm(42)` (just as a test)
2. Changed `confirm = () =>` to `confirm = (kid) =>`
3. Changed `{keyid: 42}` to `{keyid: kid}`

Which basically passes a parameter to the confirm call. I was expecting everything to work smoothly as this happened:

[image]

And as you can see, the code started to execute infinitely on itself automatically without any key presses or action, which is the problem. Can anyone please tell me the cause? Thanks in advance.

**Resources**

```js
async function postDeleteData(url = '', data = {}) {

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('method', data.method);
  formData.append('keyid', data.keyid);

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,},
    body: formData
  });
  return response.json();
}
```

```py
# Django views
class IndexView(View):
    template_name = "todo/index.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'delete' in request.POST.get("method"):
            Todo.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get("keyid")).delete()
            return JsonResponse({'success': True})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Changed confirm to confirm(42) (just as a test)

When you changed this part, you actually changed the reference to the function to the result of the function. This means it will call every time you re-render. You need to make it a function reference again, I recommend changing the `confirm(42)` to `() => confirm(42)`.